# How to create state() in component model?

Tags: joomla

I red tutorial on creating custom filters in joomla model http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_to_add_custom_filters_to_components. It's said that I have to create a custom field, so I can later use setState and getState. But I wonder if I can set custom state by simply writing:

`$this->setState('filter.custom', 'something');`

and later use it in somewhere else i.e

`getlistquery $this->getState('filter.custom');` ?

I mean... I tried this and it didn't worked, so I'm looking forward to what could be done to get it work.. ?

Comment: What are you extending?

Comment: Hi Elin, I'm extending com_content component, but I also want to use setState in module.

Comment: What happened when it "didn't work"? Did you get an error?

Comment: So you're in com_content but in which file are you working?

Comment: I guess you cannot set state from component in module.

Comment: For i.e, in articles model. I'm trying to setState in populateState function. `$this->setState('filter.custom', 'something');` and use it in getListQuery like this `$this->getState('filter.custom');` echoing this setState results in nothing, so I guess it's empty. (not set)